# how to give border to checkbox in xaml ? windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I try to add border of checkbox but it's painful for me. This fragment of code

```
  <CheckBox
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Background="White"
                BorderThickness="5"                  
                ></CheckBox>
```

doesn't work like it should. The property of BorderBrush is set, the BorderThickness also. And my checkbox is still without border like u can see on this screenshot

[image]

I tried do smth in blend, but I can't find anything useful. Can't find any helpful links to fix this issue.

UPDATED this is my whole xaml

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="checkbox.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="white">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <CheckBox BorderBrush="Black" IsChecked="true" BorderThickness="4" Foreground="Black">fafasdf</CheckBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Update

how it should look like

[image]

Comment: Can you post your xaml? there is no issue with your checkbox

Comment: This is my whole xaml code of this page

Comment: can you see the checkbox during design mode?

Comment: it looks the same like on the screenshoot so the place where tick sign appears if I click on checkbox, have no border.

Comment: well there should be some issue with the layout or your style, best way to checkout this is to remove all your styles and check it

Comment: I updated with the screen how it should look like. Now u can see nearly empty xaml, only with checkbox and still it's not working as I want :/

Comment: some wierd issue!it works well for me

Comment: yes it works with a border

Comment: so I have no idea what's the source of this problem if the code is ok